# How to have a different hostname to the fqdn?

Tags: hostname, domain-name

I have a server with fqdn git.mydomain.com (this is in DNS) but I don't really want the machine to have git as its hostname.

It might not be clear exactly what I want. Or maybe I don't really understand how all this is supposed to work, but my understanding is that

```
hostname -f
```

Should return the fqdn of the server, which in this case is git.mydomain.com

And plain old hostname should return the UNqualified hostname of the server. Every resource I can find says the the unqualified name should be the start of the fqdn **but this seems annoying and inconvenient.**

I would like

```
hostname -f
```

To return git.mydomain.com since that really is the fqdn of the server

But I would like hostname to just return mycustomhostname.

At the moment I have /etc/hostname set as 'mycustomhostname', and in /etc/hosts I have

```
127.0.0.1 mycustomhostname
1.2.3.4 git.mydomain.com
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is my public IP. However, this results in the hostname command returning mycustomhostname (which is fine), but hostname -f returns mycustomhostname as well, which is not correct, since the fqdn is git.mydomain.com.

The main reason for this is that when I am ssh'ing in to the server I would like the bash shell to say

```
myusername@mycustomhostname
```

Instead of

```
myusername@git (Which is what ever guide everywhere seems to indicate it should be).
```

Simply because it will make it easier for me to know what server I am working with. If I have another server for git repositories (say, git.mydomain2.com) and follow the conventions I see everywhere, then if I ssh'd in to that server bash would also say

```
myusername@git
```

Which is confusing for me.

How do I properly have a different hostname to the server's fqdn?

This is on Debian Linux btw.

Comment: You could create a DNS CNAME record for git.mydomain.com pointing to the server's IP or real host name server1.mydomain.com? Is there a particular reason you want `git.mydomain.com` to be the "real FQDN"? FWIW OS X's `man hostname` says: *Include domain information in the printed name.  This is the default behavior. [...] Trim off any domain information from the printed name.*. There's no reference to those being completely different.

Comment: Is the fqdn not supposed to be the domain name of the server on the Internet? If I want to access this server through a browser I type

git.mydomain.com

So therefore shouldn't that be the fqdn?

Comment: Just add two lines to your ``~/.ssh/config``: ``Host mycustomhostname`` and ``HostName git.mydomain.com``, in that order. See ``man ssh_config`` for details. This solves your original problem, but not the question as stated, so sadly not an answer. (You can even get rid of the ``myusername@`` by adding a ``User myusername`` line; just running ``ssh mycustomhostname`` does the trick then, and both suggestions even trickle down to git (pun intended))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your server the host name `mycustomhostname.example.org`, and add an alias (CNAME) in DNS for `git.example.org` to that host.

This way, it can be reached using `git.example.org`, but it'll identify using its actual host name.

Answer (score -1):

You can use as simple command:

```
# hostname -s
```

And see the result.